# Google Chrome acting weird

Tags: google-chrome, macos-bigsur

After I did the macOS Big Sur update, my Google Chrome turned into this. I can't see how to change this to normal language.
If I paste the same text and paste it into google chrome, then I can see the text in english.
What can I do to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Font Book app -> Restore standard fonts : https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/font-book/fb34862/mac

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/gsfido/all_text_on_google_pages_like_search_and_gmail/fs5tcy8/